# Is "make your own video game" on topic?

Tags: discussion

Is this question on topic?

> My 11 year old son has been asking me how he can create his own video
>   games. A few relatively short search sessions reveals hundreds sites
>   that dedicate at least some part of their real estate to this aim. I
>   don't know enough to separate the wheat from the chaff, thus this
>   question.

...and if not here, where else should I go?

Comment: We specialise in *playing* video games.  If your son is looking to MAKE video games, there's our sister site, [gamedev.SE](gamedev.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**It is not.**

There *is* a StackExchange site devoted entirely to [Game Development](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com).

Be advised however, that as with any other StackExchange site, you'll need to ask specific, answerable questions - SE isn't really suited to general beginner tutorials.

Comment: For the general questions like beginner tutorials just check the FAQs. The question isn't supposed to be asked, but it is asked all the time.