# Merge [okami] and [okami-hd]

Tags: discussion, tag-merging

Arqade currently has two separate tags for [okami](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/okami) and [okami-hd](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/okami-hd). This seems a bit redundant, considering the HD PS3 port is [nearly identical](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/92198/are-there-any-differences-between-okami-and-okami-hd-apart-of-the-graphics/308044) to the original PS2 release.

I suggest merging the two tags, making [okami-hd](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/okami-hd) a synonym for [okami](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/okami).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are noted differences between the two games. The best example I can come up with (thanks to the recent changes to the [okami](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/okami) questions) is [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/186532/162442), which asks about a mini game that is **not** present in the PS3 remake.

A question asking about the absence of that minigame would not apply to the original release of the game, only the remaster. Thus, it would require the [okami-hd](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/okami-hd) tag. As mentioned in [Robotnik's answer here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12354/162442) and fleshed out [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5379/162442), it is perfectly acceptable to have tags with only one or two uses.

Thus, I don't think [okami-hd](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/okami-hd) should be turned into a synonym of [okami](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/okami). *However*, I think that the [okami-hd](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/okami-hd) tagged questions may need to be cleaned up a bit, since not all of them address remaster-specific features (as I've noticed you've been doing lately).

Comment: It's worth noting that the loading screen mini-game was missing from both the Wii and PS3 ports HD. From what I can tell, most of the platform specific changes are shared between the Wii and PS3 releases.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro that makes the situation weird. I'd be inclined to tag the Wii port with the okami-hd tag even if it's not technically the HD version, if the features are identical to the actual HD version... either way, I think the tag is okay on its own, but that definitely does add some complexity.

Comment: From what I can tell, there are only a few minor differences between the PS2, Wii, and PS3 ports. The loading screen minigame, trophies/achievements, end credits, and Wiimote/PS Move support. I think the changes are small enough to be treated like any other multi-platform release

Comment: @StevenVascellaro agreed, but the differences appear to be substantial enough to warrant a separate tag. There are HD version-only features that would not make sense for a question given the original okami tag

Comment: Version differences are handled with the homonymous tag, aren't they? I don't really see why this is a special case.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I believe the [version-differences] tag is typically meant to be used when asking about/for comparisons between different versions of the same or related games. If you look at the questions under the tag, almost all of them are about comparisons, and many have the two related games' tags (for example, [zelda-twilight-princess] and [twilight-princess-hd], or [super-mario-64] and [super-mario-64-ds]). However, game-specific questions for a single version still have their own tags. The [okami] tag family should be no different.

Comment: @MageXy Is any difference at all enough to deserve its own tag?

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I think that any game that is "re-released" should probably have its own tag, as a rule of thumb. I'm sure there are exceptions, but that's my gut feeling.

Comment: @MageXy if a rerelease truly has no differences other than graphical ones, i wouldn't think there would need to be a separate tag. However, in this case, there are very clear differences, including a minigame that is just not in the remake, as well as other things.

Comment: Should general gameplay questions applicable to both games just be tagged with both tags? That seems fine to me.