# Do we need the [left-4-dead-series] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

The only question with [left-4-dead-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/left-4-dead-series) tag was [this question about Jesus room in No Mercy campaign](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/258030/what-is-a-jesus-spot-room), present in both *Left 4 Dead* and *Left 4 Dead 2*. Do we actually need it, as it no longer applies to any question and kinda overlaps with both [left-4-dead](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/left-4-dead) and [left-4-dead-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/left-4-dead-2)?

Comment: (Note the Left 4 Dead question was asked by myself) - I originally accepted your edit to move to using 2 game tags, but since Robotnik's answer I have rolled back to the previous version of the question.

Answer (score 17):

"Series" style tags are meant for questions that are relevant to many (or all) games in a particular series, rather than a single game.

This might not seem to make much sense for something like Left 4 Dead which (as of writing) only has two games, but look at series like:

- [The Legend of Zelda](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-breath-of-the-wild+or+zelda-skyward-sword+or+zelda-ocarina-of-time+or+zelda-link-between-worlds+or+zelda-links-awakening+or+zelda-wind-waker+or+legend-of-zelda-series+or+legend-of-zelda+or+zelda-twilight-princess+or+zelda-majoras-mask+or+zelda-link-to-the-past+or+zelda-majoras-mask-3d+or+zelda-oracle-of-seasons+or+zelda-oracle-of-ages+or+zelda-tri-force-heroes+or+zelda-four-swords-ds+or+zelda-spirit-tracks+or+zelda-wind-waker-hd+or+zelda-ocarina-of-time-3d+or+zelda-phantom-hourglass) -> [legend-of-zelda-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legend-of-zelda-series)
- [Pokemon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-go+or+pokemon-xy+or+pokemon-series+or+pokemon-sixth-gen+or+pokemon-oras+or+pokemon-sm+or+pokemon-fifth-gen+or+pokemon-first-gen+or+pokemon-hgss+or+pokemon-fourth-gen+or+pokemon-bank+or+pokemon-third-gen+or+pokemon-seventh-gen+or+pokemon-frlg+or+pokemon-rse+or+pokemon-dpp+or+pokemon-bw2+or+pokemon-second-gen+or+pokemon-bw+or+pokemon-mystery-dungeon) -> [pokemon-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-series)
- [Portal](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/portal-2+or+portal+or+portal-series+or+portal-knights+or+portal-2-peer-review) -> [portal-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/portal-series)
- [Sonic The Hedgehog](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sonic-3-and-knuckles+or+sonic-all-stars-racing+or+sonic-3+or+sonic-the-hedgehog+or+sonic-generations+or+sonic-the-hedgehog-series+or+sonic-and-knuckles+or+sonic-all-stars-racing-tf+or+sonic-the-hedgehog-4-ep-1+or+sonic-the-hedgehog-2006+or+sonic-the-hedgehog-2+or+sonic-adventure-2-battle+or+sonic-cd+or+sonic-unleashed+or+sonic-the-hedgehog-4-ep-2+or+sonic-dreams-collection+or+sonic-rivals+or+sonic-lost-world+or+sonic-jump-fever+or+sonic-black-knight) -> [sonic-the-hedgehog-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sonic-the-hedgehog-series)

Each of these 'series' tags contain questions which span across multiple games, regardless of how many games in the series there are. The series tags are for series-level content - *not* individual games. So why shouldn't we have a Left 4 Dead series tag that does the same thing?

To apply the same logic as I discussed in [Do we really need this “longplay” tag?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12354/28182)

#### 1. Does it provide a useful 'overarching' grouping of like-minded content?

**Yes.** As discussed above, series tags are for questions that span a series, not for questions about individual games. Likewise in reverse, individual game tags should be used questions about that specific game - not for questions about the overarching series.

#### 2. Is the only (current) question a valid use of the tag?

I say **Yes**: The question is a [terminology](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) question that applies to the Left 4 Dead community and multiplayer regardless of whether Left 4 Dead 1 or 2 was being played. If/when a hypothetical 'Left 4 Dead 3' comes out, the question will just as likely apply to that game as well, assuming the glitch/mechanic remains in that game as well.

#### 3. Do we keep tags with only one question?

**We do!** There is a [relevant meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5379/stop-removing-tags-that-are-only-used-once-in-the-last-6-months) where Stack Exchange even disabled the script that deletes tags because it was causing us a lot of headaches.

#### 4. Can [left-4-dead-series] be useful as a 'specific' topic area?

I believe so, for the points discussed above.

Thus I think the tag is relevant and useful and should continue to be used for it's one question.

Comment: "Does it provide a useful 'overarching' grouping of like-minded content?" -- nope, was only one question with that tag, and "series" is only two games as of current. "Is the only (current) question a valid use of the tag?" -- No, it applies to both games, but we can't know if the glitch will be kept in subsequent games. Question about the series could be, for example, "How is the infection transferred?", or "Why was Zoey wrong about killing her father?", because they apply to the lore of series, but this is a technical question about a likely unintended feature.

Comment: Having only one question use a tag is not a reason to not use the tag. The tag itself and it's usage follows the convention of other series tags - they aren't *'just'* for story/lore, otherwise the tag would be [left-4-dead-lore]. The question is about terminology as used in the community, not the glitch itself. If the question asked how to use/access the Jesus room, that's when the game tag will be relevant.

Answer (score -4):

My opinion is that [left-4-dead-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/left-4-dead-series) has to be purged. I think that questions that apply to both games should just have both [left-4-dead](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/left-4-dead) and [left-4-dead-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/left-4-dead-2) on them.